# How to draw three graphs on the same plane with nodes

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-node, scoping, tikz-path

I am relative new on latex, I therefore request somebody to assist with a code of drawing three graphs (see attached picture):
[image]

Below is the MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{syntonly}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx,color}
\usepackage{epstopdf,bm}
\usepackage{fancyhdr,multirow,array,tikz,color,rotating}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,arrows,positioning}
\tikzset{main node/.style={circle,fill=blue!20,draw,minimum size=1cm,inner sep=0pt},}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[main node] (i) {$i$};
\node[main node] (j) [below left = 2.3cm and 1.5cm of i]  {$j$};
\node[main node] (k) [below right = 2.3cm and 1.5cm of i] {$k$};

\path[draw,thick]
%(i) edge node {} (j)
(j) edge node {} (k)
;
%%
\begin{scope}[xshift=5.9cm]
\node[main node] (k) {$k$};
\node[main node] (j) [below left = 2.3cm and 1.5cm of k]  {$j$};
\node[main node] (i) [below right = 2.3cm and 1.5cm of k] {$i$};

\path[draw,thick]
(j) edge node {} (i)
;
\end{scope}

\begin{scope}[xshift=11.9cm]
\node[main node] (j) {$j$};
\node[main node] (i) [below left = 2.3cm and 1.5cm of j]  {$i$};
\node[main node] (k) [below right = 2.3cm and 1.5cm of j] {$k$};

\path[draw,thick]
(i) edge node {} (k)
;
\end{scope}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX-SX. This is a pretty void message. Please elaborate (and feel free to read the rules, you may to need to comply to some of them).

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Edit:**
Like this?

[image: Possible Desired Output]

With use of `subcaption` package and intersection coordinates for line driving (marked by `% <---` in code). With use of the `quotes` are now added edge labels `$x_i$` and `$y_i$`:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{syntonly}
\usepackage{geometry}

\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
                positioning,
                quotes}             % <--- added
\tikzset{node distance = 13mm and 11mm,
           C/.style = {circle,draw, fill=blue!20,
                       minimum size=1cm, inner sep=0pt},
         dot/.style = {circle, fill=black, inner sep=2pt,
                       node contents={} },,
         every edge quotes/.style = {auto, font=\small} % <--- added
        }

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[ht]
    
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\textwidth}
\caption{}
\label{subfig:1}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
\node (j) [C, label=$j$] {};
\node [dot];
\node (i) [C, below right = of j, label=below:$i$] {};
\node (k) [C, above right = of i, label=$k$] {};
%
\draw[thick]    (i |- j) to ["$y_i$"] (i)               % <--- changed
                (j.center) to [pos=0.6, "$x_i$"] (k);   % <--- changed
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{subfigure}
\hfill
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\textwidth}
\caption{}
\label{subfig:2}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
\node (j) [C, label=$j$] {};
\node [dot];
\node (i) [C, below right = of j, label=below:$i$] {};
\node (k) [C, above right = of i, label=$k$] {};
%
\draw[thick]    (i |- j) to ["$y_i$"] (i)               % <--- changed
                (j.center) to [pos=0.6, "$x_i$"] (k);   % <--- changed
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{subfigure}
\hfill
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\textwidth}
\caption{}
\label{subfig:3}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
\node (j) [C, label=$j$] {};
\node [dot];
\node (i) [C, below right = of j, label=below:$i$] {};
\node (k) [C, above right = of i, label=$k$] {};
%
\draw[thick]    (i |- j) to ["$y_i$"] (i)               % <--- changed
                (j.center) to [pos=0.6, "$x_i$"] (k);   % <--- changed
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{subfigure}

\caption{Three graphs}
\label{fig:figure}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks Zarko, I'm also trying to label the lines/edges with X_i,X_j and etc. and also increase the size of the node "J".

Comment: @HappyVilakazi, see edited answer. Now edge labels are added.

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: @HappyVilakazi, you are welcome. BTW, policy of this site is that instead say "thank you" upvote answer and  if the answer solve your problem (on the best way), you accept them (by clicking on check mark at top left side of answer).